# Modify arguments passed to a variadic function inside that function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

The following code does not compile. How can I modify the `args` variables inside `get_numbers_from_line_variadic`?

The non-variadic version `get_numbers_from_line` illustrates what the variadic one is supposed to achieve, however, with variable number of arguments possibly with different types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template<typename... ArgTypes>
void get_numbers_from_line_variadic(std::string line, ArgTypes&... args)
{
   std::istringstream iss(line);

   for (auto& arg : {args...})
      iss >> arg;
}

void get_numbers_from_line(std::string line, int& a, int& b)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> a;
    iss >> b;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    get_numbers_from_line("1 2", a, b);
    get_numbers_from_line_variadic("1 2", a, b);

    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `((args = 2), ...);`?

Comment: Doesn't work: **error: expected primary-expression before '...' token**. Furthermore, the arguments will be changed in a more complicated way - not just all to 2. This is just to simplify the question.

Comment: `ArgTypes&` -> `ArgTypes&&`

Comment: @M.M Not if the function makes no sense for rvalue arguments, like this one.

Comment: No - exactly the same error as before

Comment: @user3749105 the way you are changing the arguments is central to the question. It would improve the question to show something more representative of the real code

Comment: Since C++17, `(args = ... = 2);` and `((args = 2), ...);` are both legal

Comment: @aschepler It wouldn't be an rvalue reference, but a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: @DanielH Yes. But a universal reference is used when you want to accept both lvalues and rvalues. If the purpose of the function is to assign to the parameters, it's better to cause compiler errors if someone uses an rvalue parameter than to silently allow a useless assignment.

Comment: @aschepler Fair enough. It doesn't make much sense to pass rvalues into this function, but it might still be a good idea for whatever the non-MCVE version is.

Comment: @M.M: sorry, I didn't know that the way the variables are changed would make any difference. I modified the question and put the real code there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first overload (base function) is called only when there is no [parameter pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).
The second overload is a recursive variadic function that separates the head of the pack from the tail (rest of parameter pack). This enables passing only the tail recursively until it becomes empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void get_numbers_from_line(std::istringstream&){} // base function

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void get_numbers_from_line(std::istringstream& iss, T&& head, Ts&&... tail) // recursive variadic function
{
    iss >> head;
    get_numbers_from_line(iss, std::forward<Ts>(tail)...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
void get_numbers_from_line(std::string line, Ts&&... args)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    get_numbers_from_line(iss, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    double a;
    int b, c;
    get_numbers_from_line("-0.1 2 3", a, b, c);

    std::cout << "a = " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b = " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c = " << c << std::endl;
}
```

[Fold expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) version (since C++17):

```
template<typename... Ts>
void get_numbers_from_line(std::string line, Ts&&... args)
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    (iss >> ... >> std::forward<Ts>(args));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had to modify the question to put the real code there.

Comment: Great! I simplified a little bit, got rid of the old part and accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble here is that when a type is deduced directly from a braced-init-list, the deduced type is a specialization of `std::initializer_list`, and `std::initializer_list` only allows `const` access to its elements.

In a bit more detail, your range-based `for` statement is similar to the loop:

```
{
    auto&& range = {args...};      // std::initializer_list<int>&&
    auto iter = range.begin();     // const int*
    auto end  = range.end();       // const int*
    for (; iter != end; ++iter) {
        auto& arg = *iter;         // const int&
        iss >> arg;                // ERROR
    }
}
```

since `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` is `const T*`.

You will need to process the function parameters more directly.

As noted in the comments, if you are using C++17 (or later), you can use a fold expression.

```
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    (iss >> ... >> args);
}
```

If using C++11 or C++14, you can use the dummy array initialization trick instead:

```
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    // Note (expr, 0) to discard expression result and supply int
    // for the array, and final 0 in case sizeof...(args)==0
    int dummy[] = { (iss >> args, 0)..., 0 };
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid unused variable warning
}
```

Comment: If the problem is that `std::initializer_list` only allows `const` access, if you need the more complicated loop then could `for (auto& a : {&args...})
      *a = 2;` work? The pointers are `const` in that case, but you can still mutate through them.

Comment: Oh, with my own testing that only works if all the parameters are the same type, or it can't deduce the type parameter for the initializer list.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way to do it.  And yes, in `auto&& il = {expressions};` or `for (auto&& e : {expressions})`, the type deduced from each expression in the list must be the same type, which could be another issue with the OP function if that wasn't an intentional restriction.

Comment: @aschepler: thank you for your answer, however, the way how the variables are modified seems to be important, so I had to put the real code in the question. How about now?

Comment: @user3749105 Same deal, just a different expression to expand. Edited my answer to match.

Comment: What if the arguments are not all ints? They will have different types.